# Blinking 3 LEDs using PIC 18F4550

Tags: c, embedded, pic, microchip, mplab

I'm trying to get myself started with the PIC 18F4550 using the C, MPLAB X (both IDE and IPE) and using the PICKit 3.
I've managed to blink one LED without any problems, but as I try to blink more than one LED at simultaneously, it doesn't work.

*Please note that I will post my full code at the end of the question. Until then, I'll be writing pseudocode in hope of making my question a little bit clearer.*

Assume I want to blink 4 LEDs, each attached to an output pin of the chip, you'd obviously type something like

```
loop{
     output1 = 1;
     output2 = 1;
     output3 = 1;
     output4 = 1;
     delay();
     output1 = 0;
     output2 = 0;
     output3 = 0;
     output4 = 0;
     delay();
}
```

You would expect that all of the LEDs would turn on and off simultaneously. However, I noticed that only the LED connected to output4 would blink and the rest would remain turned off.
So I tried flipping the order of the output pins as such

```
 loop{
         output1 = 1;
         output2 = 1;
         output4 = 1;
         output3 = 1;
         delay();
         output1 = 0;
         output2 = 0;
         output4 = 0;
         output3 = 0;
         delay();
    }
```

As a result, only the LED attached to output 3 would blink, and the rest would remain turned off.

So I figured, somehow, the code is not executing sequentially as I'd expected it to do so.
Can anyone please provide me with an explanation and a possible solution for this?

Thanks a lot!

Here's the full code

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <p18f4450.h>
#pragma config FOSC = HS

#define outRed  PORTBbits.RB0
#define outBlue PORTBbits.RB1
#define outYellow PORTBbits.RB2
#define outGreen PORTBbits.RB3
#define _XTAL_FREQ 10000000

void delay(unsigned int);



void main(void) {
    TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB1 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB2 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 0;

    while(1) {
        outRed = 1;
        outGreen = 1;
        outBlue = 1;
        outYellow = 1;
        delay(1000);   
        outRed = 0;
        outGreen = 0;
        outBlue = 0;
        outYellow = 0;
        delay(1000);
    }        

}

void delay(unsigned int delayInput) {
    unsigned int mul = delayInput/50;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count <= mul; count ++)
        __delay_ms(50);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a LATCH issue. I have had this problem a few times when I started up. Try writing to the LATB (output latch) register instead of the PORTB register. I always use the LATx for output and the PORTx for input.

Comment: This worked out quite well for me! Thanks a lot!
Is there a reason for this issue however? In the architecture of the PIC? I mean why is it that this happens?

Comment: The PORTx read from the digital input buffers whereas the LATx write to the output latches. In some circumstances, the digital input buffers wont see the voltage that you are trying to output with the LATx registers (ex. if any of the pins are set as analog inputs, they will read as a 0). Combine that with the fact that the bit operations are implemented with an 8 bit read=>modify=>write, your PORTx results may be surprising. P.S. Some of the PIC18F4550's pins can be configured as analog or digital inputs using the ADCON1 register.

Answer (score 0):

Always write to the output latches (in your case LATB) and read inputs from PORTx. Writing to PORTx has unpredictable behaviour.